# Rails using a layout for new and edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, layout

In my application I have a form for a new action that is the same, four or five lines apart, that my edit form.

The problem that i encounter is that my new.html.haml gives me an error explainning that it doesn't know what "f" is.

The f is the one in "form_for @object do |f|".

Obviously in my new the form_for's object is not the same that the edit one.

I think that it should be a common behaviour but i can't seem to find anything that suits my needs in the rails documentation.

Here a quick exemple of code

```
#new.html.haml
%div{ id: "StaticForms" }
 = f.label :project_id
 = f.collection_select :project_id, @projects, :id, :name,
 { selected: @edit.task.project_id },
 { class: "form-control", onchange: 'get_projects(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);' }
 - index = 1
 - @project_tree.each do |task|
   = render partial: "edit", locals: {task: task, index: index} // render here was okay before "layouting"
   - index += 1

 #form_layout.html.haml%html
 %div{ :class => "col-md-12" }
   %h2 Reporting
     %div{ :id => "Form"}
       = form_for @activity do |f|

       = f.label :consultant_id
       = f.collection_select :consultant_id, @consultants, :id, :name,
       { selected: current_user.consultant.id },
       { class: "form-control" }

       = yield
```

The JS tag "onchange: ..." you can see on the new.html.haml file is supposed to be triggered by JS that i have in the layout file fyi.

The error i have is : "undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x007feb84e6b848>"

Can someone help with a link or an explanation ? :)

Thank you.
Best regards.

Edit : Added some code, did not think it was relevent for that type of issue :>

Comment: it would be helpful if u share the code...

Comment: I think you might be better off using partials - layouts are generally meant to reshape the entire page - not for reusable components.

Comment: You should also extract your javascript in a file in `assets/javascripts`. Putting your javascript in your views is a very poor practice and you're really just making things harder on yourself and others as its really hard to follow the flow when its split across views.

Comment: To @max Thx for your concerns, i'm familiar with that practise, the fact is i have to wait before taking this code into it's own file.

for the partial part, i really thought that since the code i want to put in a layout is the entire content of both pages, a layout would have been more relevent than a partial. thx for your answers, i'll check that right away :)

Comment: I changed it, trying to render a partial instead of a layout.. I still got my issue with the block variable that's unknow in my new or edit view :/

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/views/activities/_form.haml
= form_for activity do |f|
   = f.label :consultant_id
   = f.collection_select :consultant_id, @consultants, :id, :name,
       { selected: current_user.consultant.id },
       { class: "form-control" }
   ...

#app/views/activities/new.haml
= render "form", activity: @activity

#app/views/activities/edit.haml
= render "form", activity: @activity
```

Answer (score 0):

So i finnaly get around my problem and i was able to fix it.

new and edit views :

```
= render layout: 'form_activity', locals: {activity: @object} do |f| # here @objet depends on the controller method i.e. @activity for new, @edit for edit
  = f.label ...
  ...

#relativly the same code in edit and new
```

_from_activity.html.haml (in the same folder than the views above) :

```
= form_for activity do |f|
... # some form stuff
= yield f # here i get back to new or edit code
... # some stuff - rest of the form.
```

This works perfectly !

Layout stuff -- before the yield.

--

Views stuff - thanks to the line : 1) render layout: ... do | **f** | in the view and 2) yield **f** in the layout

--

Layout stuff - after the yield.

Thx all of you for your answers.

By the way, i'm aware that the first question wasn't asking the result i just post. If so my apologies :/

Best regards.